# Render the Acute accent when I create a xls file with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, xls

When I create a xls file with acute accent this do this in the Excel file:
NÃºmero, but the correct word is "Número".

I have this code:

```
                    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
                    string attachment;
                    if (Request.QueryString["AutorizacionAcceso"] != null)
                    {
                        attachment = "attachment; filename=AutorizaciónAcceso.xls";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attachment = "attachment; filename=segmentacionMundoNet.xls";
                    }

                    Page.Form.Target = "_blank";
                    Page.Response.ClearContent();
                    Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                    Page.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                    Page.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
                    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
                    form.Controls.Add(gvResultados);
                    this.Controls.Add(form);
                    form.RenderControl(htextw);
                    Page.Response.Write(stw.ToString());
                    Page.Response.End();
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the ú with this string "& uacute;" (No separation between the & and uacute.

[Here is a listing](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html#accent) of the Codes for special characters

Have a look at this [page](http://www.hugoleonardo.net/2013/03/corrigir-acentos-do-arquivo-csv-para.html), it's in spanish though

Comment: The problem is that in the HTML "número" sees good but in the excel file no